# GAE by using GQL, how to use SQL's like query?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

def post(self):

```
    selector = self.request.get('search')
    search = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE productName = :selector", selector=selector)
    products = search.fetch(10)
    values = {
        'products' : products
        }
    doRender(self, 'search.html', values)
```

above code is for search function from my Product category...
Actually i tried to use the code "Select * From Product Where productName like %:selector%"
for my search function, but i couldn't use this code....
Is there anyother GQL code which is substitution of 'SQL-LIKE query'??

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of SQL's LIKE in App Engine. You can however do something like

```
blurred_product_name = selector[:-2]
search = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Product where productName > ',
                                          blurred_product_name)
```

So, if you have products with the name Product-1, Product-2, Product-3 and the search term is "Product", your blirred_product_name will be "Produc" which will return all the three possibilities in this case.
Be careful with indexes however.

Alternatively you can very well use SearchableModel http://www.billkatz.com/2008/8/A-SearchableModel-for-App-Engine  and get this done easily.